# Why must a ring homomorphism from $\mathbb Q[\sqrt n] \to R$ be the identity mapping?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-homomorphism

Let $\mathbb Q[\sqrt d]:= \{a+b\sqrt d \, |\, a,b \in \mathbb Q\}$, and $d\in \mathbb N$ with the condition that $d$ is not a square number. I have shown that this is a subring of $\mathbb R$ and that for each $d$ there can only be two automorphisms, but this question utterly perplexes me. If $R$ is another ring which contains $\mathbb Q$ as a subring, then why must a homomorphism $\varphi : \mathbb Q[\sqrt d] \to R $ be the identity mapping? Ie, why must $\varphi (x) = x \quad \forall x \in \mathbb Q$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, from $\varphi(1)=1$ it follows that $\varphi(n) = n$. Hence, if $q= a/b \in \mathbb{Q}$ where $a$ and $b$ are integers, we have
$$\varphi(q) = \varphi(ab^{-1}) = \varphi(a)\varphi(b)^{-1}= ab^{-1}= q$$

Moreover, consider the mapping
$$\varphi: \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d}) \to \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d}): a+ b \sqrt{d}\mapsto a - b \sqrt{d}$$
Check that this is a ring isomorphism. Hence, $\varphi$ need not be the identity.

Comment: It seems you forgot to deal with $\varphi(\sqrt d)$.

Comment: @Christoph The OP does not state this in the question. He asks for $\varphi(x) = x$ for $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ (see last sentence).

Comment: It seems the OP forgot to ask about it as well then. Otherwise there would be no reason to use $\mathbb Q[\sqrt d]$ at all and also asking "why must $\varphi\colon\mathbb Q[\sqrt d]\to R$ be the identity mapping" doesn't sound like it only considers $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: @Christoph Fair point, but we are not even given that $\sqrt{d}\in R$, so how would you show that you have an identity on more than the rationals?

Comment: Since $\sqrt{d}\cdot \sqrt{d} = d$ we must have $\varphi(\sqrt{d}) \cdot \varphi(\sqrt{d}) = \varphi(d) = d$ so that $\varphi(\sqrt{d})^2 = d$, meaning that $\varphi(\sqrt{d})$ is *a* square root of $d$ in $R$.

Comment: @Christoph Sure, but this does not mean that $\varphi(\sqrt{d})= \sqrt{d}$, which is what the question asks for.

Comment: To clarify; it was not a mistake. However now quantum has aroused my curiosity. Why would that be the case?

Comment: What's your definition of $\sqrt{r}$ for an element $r$ in a ring $R$? You have to make a choice and there are two ways to do this in a consistent fashion in this example. The only non-trivial automorphism of $\mathbb Q[\sqrt d]$ mentioned by OP is the one sending $\sqrt d$ to $-\sqrt d$.

Comment: @Christoph Yes, and that example shows that we don't need to have an identity on the entire ring, but only restricted on the rationals. Could you explain me how this does not answer the question?

Comment: The usage of the word "identity" in this question is very misleading: the elements of $\mathbb Q[\sqrt d]$ or $\mathbb Q$ need not be elements of $R$ (considered just as elements of sets). The only way we can make sense of an equation like $\varphi(2)=2$ in this setting is by defining $2\in R$ to be $1_R+1_R$. Hence, even asking whether $\varphi(\sqrt d)=\sqrt d$ demands a definition of what $\sqrt{d}$ as an element of $R$ means. Given $\varphi$, we can define $\sqrt{d}\in R$ as $\varphi(\sqrt d)$ and obtain $\varphi(a+b\sqrt{d})=a+b\sqrt{d}$ for all $a,b\in\mathbb Q$.

Comment: @Christoph It is given that $\mathbb{Q}$ is a subring of $R$, so we can safely say that $\varphi$ is really the identity map on $\mathbb{Q}$, but that's where it stops and your comment becomes relevant.

Comment: You're right, I missed that!

Comment: I think we are in complete agreement then. Thanks for the fruitful discussion :)

Comment: Each time I've tried to comment I've noticed that just before I post one of you has answered my question. I do appreciate the insight though, this makes sense. Many thanks to both of you!